# Passar e receber dados para servlet na mesma function AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlet

Tem alguma forma de enviar parâmetro para servlet e receber um json na mesma function AJAX?
Exemplo do que eu preciso:

```
 function UpdateGrafico(){

          $(function () {

                //---------------------
       //aqui preciso enviar uma data para o servlet realizar um select        
      $.ajax({  
     data: "",  
     dataType: 'json',  
     url: './GetValores', 
     type: 'POST', 
     success: function(data){  

           //recebe os dados json e atualiza pagina 
        });
    }
```

Preciso desta forma porque na página JSP tem um botão e quando eu clicar nele, será pego uma data que o usuário selecionou, e utilizada esta data para um select no servlet, que retornará os dados para atualizar um gráfico na página JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta, segue abaixo:

```
 function UpdateGrafico(){

          $(function () {

                //---------------------
       //aqui preciso enviar uma data para o servlet realizar um select        
      $.ajax({  
     data: varival: "valor1", //aqui passa o valor para o servlet 
     dataType: 'json',  
     url: './GetValores', //nome do servlet
     type: 'POST', 
     success: function(data){  

           //recebe os dados json e atualiza pagina 
        });
    }
```